# Задать полупрозрачность линейному градиенту

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как задать полупрозрачность линейному градиенту?

Вот код:

```
.header {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url(../img/header__bg.jpg) no-repeat center -100px / cover;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#fce38a, #f38181);
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.sunhome.ru/cards/113/otkritki-valentine-s-day-kartinki.orig.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.gradient {
    width: 100wh;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(252,227,138,.85), rgba(243,129,129,.85));
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```